# How long is the "temporary" account ban from bungie/Halo Reach?

Tags: xbox-network, halo-reach

Neither my friend or I have ever been banned. We got the message on his console that both of our accounts, as well as the console, had been banned from earning credits. It pointed us to view the information at [www.bungie.net/ban](http://www.bungie.net/ban)
Bungie's website is very vague about the ban durations.

> The duration of this ban will be based on the type, frequency or nature of the committed violation.

But nowhere do they list ban time frames by offense.

> Types of violation include, but are not limited to, the following example actions:
>
> - Manipulating network conditions to give yourself an advantage, or to the detriment of the experience for other players.
> - Modifying your Xbox 360 hardware or Bungie software and services in any way.
> - Skill, EXP, or Credit Boosting, deleveling, idling through games, cheating, habitual quitting or any other type of **unsociable and unsportsmanlike behavior.**
> - Impersonating a Bungie employee on Xbox LIVE with intent to defraud or cause harm to other players.

I placed in bold the only reason they list that could have caused us to get banned.

It is our fault, although definitely not malicious. We left the game in the matchmaking lobby and my friends 4 year old son, having watched us for countless hours play, decided he wanted to. I'm guessing he was playing for about an hour before we came back to play, and he had gone through quite a few games getting betrayals.

I logged into my bungie account and also could not see anywhere on my profile where they would state any information regarding the ban or the time frame. It simply says "temporary" yet it has been 3 days now and the ban is still in place.

Comment: Usually its Microsoft who bans you, not Bungie. Can you play other Xbox games online? If not whats you gamer tag?

Comment: I can still play Halo Reach matchmaking...I just don't earn any credits doing so. As far as I can tell I still collect badges, and the K/D ratio is saved...but I get no credits for the game.

Comment: My friend and I were playing Halo: REACH one night and I stopped playing because I got bored. I set down my controller while my friend was trying to get the Jackpot for the weekend. 4-7 games later we had received a message in-game that both the account and the console had been temporarily banned from earning credits. This sucks, but I have to learn from my lessons. My guess would be that you and I are probably banned for at least 24 hours. I don't have that much experience with ban hammers, but what I do know is that it was a vague mistake and won't happen again.... I wanted the jackpot reall

Comment: I was banned because my friends network connection kept expiring which counted as quit games, and i decided it was pointless to play if i cant earn cR, so i got on the next day and it was lifted, so i think it depends on what you do, please see [Bungies](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=68409507&postRepeater1-p=1#68409813) response to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been unable to find anything documented anywhere stating the time frame of the "Temporary" bans based on the offense. My ban was finally lifted 1 week after it was instated. I would venture that this is probably a standard time frame for the first offense of unsportsmanlike conduct.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, I believe the first time is 24 hours and the second is 1 week.

Comment: Is there anywhere this information is documented? This is definitely the first time I have been banned from anything and it has been 3 days.

Comment: I don't believe any official documents have ban lengths documented as they reserve the right to ban you for however long they want for an infraction.  You can look around on the internet but the general consensus is 24 hours the first time, then 1 week for the second.  It possibly varies on the severity of the infraction.  You might try calling Xbox Live's support line to ask how long your ban will last.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not Xbox Live that initiated the ban. From Bungies site: 

`Please note that while this process is automated, it is accurate. Bans are almost certainly legitimate, and will stay in force for their stated duration. To keep your matchmaking privileges in good standing, immediately cease any unsociable behavior and wait out the ban. Either way, there will be no response communication from this process.`

Comment: Its been 48 hours for me and its still on ban and this is my 1st time getting banned.

Comment: Do you play every day?  If not you might have missed a 24 hour ban.